# Traffic light using css change by adding javascript to control the timer

Tags: javascript, html, css

**i found this code online which timer is controled in css.how do i control it with javascript.i have tried new ways but failed.anyone able to help me out.What im actually trying is to control the javascript  function with button click,once the button is clicked then it should call the function to run the lights based on timer which i tried early using settimeout and by setinterval but i could make it.for example red 5 seconds,orange 3 seconds and green 10 seconds,onlick this function should run.

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(#08f, #fff);
  padding: 40px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.protector {
  background: transparent;
  width: 180px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -35px;
  border-right: solid 30px transparent;
  border-left: solid 30px transparent;
  border-top: solid 90px #111;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.protector:nth-child(2) {
  top: 140px;
}

.protector:nth-child(3) {
  top: 260px;
}

.trafficlight {
  background: #222;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 2%, #111 2%, transparent 3%, #111 30%);
  width: 170px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #333;
}

.trafficlight:before {
  background: #222;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#444, #000);
  content: "";
  width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.trafficlight:after {
  background: #222;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-0deg, #444, #ccc 30%, #000);
  content: "";
  width: 75px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  background-image: radial-gradient(brown, transparent);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 35px;
  animation: 15s red infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #111 inset, 0 0 10px red;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  background-image: radial-gradient(orange, transparent);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 35px;
  animation: 13s yellow infinite;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #111 inset, 0 0 10px yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  background-image: radial-gradient(lime, transparent);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  left: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #111 inset, 0 0 10px lime;
  animation: 13s green infinite;
}

@keyframes red {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes yellow {
  0% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes green {
  0% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="trafficlight">
  <div class="protector"></div>
  <div class="protector"></div>
  <div class="protector"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

**

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript code you have tried?

Comment: Remove the animation from the CSS. Then you can use a CSS transition to control the duration and fading effects and have the button click change the classname of the element to trigger that transition. That is, if the issue is trigger onclick. If the issue is that you cannot use CSS transitions or animations, you'll have to recreate the entire fading and timing thing in javascript yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".trafficlight").click(function(){
                         $(this).toggleClass("start")
                         })
```

```css
html {
  background: linear-gradient(#08f, #fff);
  padding: 40px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.protector {
  background: transparent;
  width: 180px;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -35px;
  border-right: solid 30px transparent;
  border-left: solid 30px transparent;
  border-top: solid 90px #111;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.protector:nth-child(2) {
  top: 140px;
}

.protector:nth-child(3) {
  top: 260px;
}

.trafficlight {
  background: #222;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 2%, #111 2%, transparent 3%, #111 30%);
  width: 170px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #333;
}

.trafficlight:before {
  background: #222;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#444, #000);
  content: "";
  width: 170px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.trafficlight:after {
  background: #222;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-0deg, #444, #ccc 30%, #000);
  content: "";
  width: 75px;
  height: 800px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  background-image: radial-gradient(brown, transparent);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity:0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 35px;

  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #111 inset, 0 0 10px red;
}
.start .red{
    animation: 15s red infinite;
}
.start .yellow {
    animation: 13s yellow infinite;
}
.start .green{
    animation: 13s green infinite;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  background-image: radial-gradient(orange, transparent);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0;
  top: 145px;
  left: 35px;

  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #111 inset, 0 0 10px yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  background-image: radial-gradient(lime, transparent);
  background-size: 5px 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  opacity:0;
  left: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #111 inset, 0 0 10px lime;
}

@keyframes red {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes yellow {
  0% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
}

@keyframes green {
  0% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  95% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trafficlight">
  <div class="protector"></div>
  <div class="protector"></div>
  <div class="protector"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

i managed to make it work on click with jquery!

Comment: tq @adel helped in some way.